# How to set parameter zero ($0) while executing a script?

Tags: shell-script

I can manipulate positional parameters using `shift` or `set --` while a script is interpreted.

How can I change `$0`?

Comment: What do you want? Changing its value while the script is executed? What for? Don't you have enough parameters? Why would you want to change special parameter $0?

Comment: `0=new-value` in `zsh` or `es`. `set 0 new-value` in `fish`. `zsh` sets `$0` to the name of the function in functions. Same in ksh when the function is declared with `function f { ... }`

Comment: This is also discussed on sof [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487488/how-to-change-argv0-value-in-shell-bash-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407615/how-to-change-argv0-value-using-bash-shell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bash greater than or equal to 5 you can change `$0` like this:

```
$ cat bar.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
BASH_ARGV0=lol
echo $0
$ ./bar.sh 
./bar.sh
lol
```

ZSH even supports assigning directly to `0`:

```
$ cat foo.zsh
#!/bin/zsh
echo $0
0=lol
echo $0
$ ./foo.zsh 
./foo.zsh
lol
```

Comment: You may run into a memory-unmap pointer problem setting $0 in zsh 5.0.2. See travis-ci.org/rocky/zshdb/builds/… However zsh 5.4.2 seems okay. And right now I don't think there is a way to set $0 in ksh up to 2020.0.0-beta1-149-g286203fc –

Answer (score 5):

Other than what Stephane has already mentioned, the only other ways I can think to do it involve invoking an `sh` process - which means your function might as well be a script. But if you're still interested:

```
fn() { sh -c "$(cat)" arg0 "$@" ; } <<\FNDEF
    echo "My argv0 is $0 and my positionals are..."
    printf %s\\n "$@"
#END
FNDEF
fn arg1 arg2 arg3 
###OUTPUT###
My argv0 is arg0 and my positionals are...
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

It's not terribly useful, though, I don't think.